# How to scroll through chart series in excel with arrow hotkeys?

Tags: excel, hotkeys

One used to be able to 'scroll' through the series in an Excel chart by pressing the up or down arrow keys. This no longer works in Microsoft 365.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is probably better suited for https://superuser.com/.

Comment: good point. should I delete this post? what is protocol?

Comment: Sure, you can delete and repost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press ALT-ArrowKey to cycle through the series.